# Python Recursion List Output returns last element multiple times

Tags: python, list, recursion, return

I'm trying to create a list of all possible combinations of a list "places", that fulfil a condition. Unfortunately my function returns only the result of the last recursion and that one several times. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here's what I have so far:

```
places = [0,1,2,3,4] #these are the values that the combinations are made of
distance = [1,2,1,2,1] #these are the distances of each place

def get_combinations(combi, i):

    # go a level higher and count to the next item
    if i == 5:
        i = places.index(combi[-1])
        combi.pop()
        return get_combinations(combi, i+1)
    
    # add place to the current list
    combi.append(places[i])

    d = sum(distance[i] for i in combi)

    if d <= max_d:
        print(combi) #This is what I want in the final list
     
        if combi == [places[4]]: # this is the base case
            return combi
        else: 
            return combi + get_combinations(combi, i+1)   

    else: 
        if combi == [places[4]]: # this is the base case
            return []
        else:    
            combi.pop()
            return get_combinations(combi, i+1)

combi = []
x = 0
max_d = 3

result = get_combinations(combi, x)
print("List of all combinations: ", result)

[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 2]
[0, 2, 4]
[0, 3]
[0, 4]
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 4]
[2]
[2, 3]
[2, 4]
[3]
[3, 4]
[4]
List of all combinations:  [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Based on the print output I can tell that the function is technically working the way I want it to.
But the function output should look like this: [[0],[0, 1],[0, 2],[0, 2, 4],[0, 3],[0, 4],[1],[1, 2],[1, 4],[2],[2, 3],[2, 4],[3],[3, 4],[4]]

What is wrong with my return statements or is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that `combi` is *returned* in `return combi`, but is also mutated later on with calls to `pop` and `append`... which still affect the list that was returned (since it is the *same* list).

To avoid that, make sure to never return `combi` itself, but a copy.

Secondly, you'll want to return a list of lists and not concatenate combinations with `combi +` into one long list. This should be a nested list.

So change:

```
        if combi == [places[4]]: # this is the base case
            return combi
        else: 
            return combi + get_combinations(combi, i+1)
```

to:

```
        if combi == [places[4]]: # this is the base case
            return [combi[:]]
        else: 
            return [combi[:]] + get_combinations(combi, i+1)
```